# Problem with magic get method

Tags: php

I am trying to write my own magic __get method in php.
But  am getting this error:
__get() must take exactly 1 argument.
The error is referring to the last line in the function below.

Any idea's?

```
public function __get()
{
    $method = 'get'.ucfirst($name);
    if(!method_exists($this, $method))
            throw new Exception('Invalid property');
    var_dump($method);
    return $this->{$method}();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your first line to

```
public function __get($name) {
```

http://no.php.net/__get

Answer (score 2):

Pass in `$name`:

```
public function __get($name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this better?

```
public function __get($name)
{
    $method = 'get'.ucfirst($name);
    if(!method_exists($this, $method))
            throw new Exception('Invalid property');
    var_dump($method);
    return $this->{$method}();

}
```

I added the name argument.

Answer (score 2):

The magic get function required exactly one argument, like the error said. Please try the following code:

```
public function __get( $name )
```

Answer (score 1):

you must specify a parameter that refers to the variable name you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1):

one argument is missing in __get($name) function.
Which will give you the value of required variable.

```
public function __get($name) {
...
...
}
```